# How to upload multiple files using multiple input filed in Laravel 7?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working on HRMS project, In that I'm saving employees data, Storing like ID Proof, Resume etc. But while uploading it gives me error as in screenshot.

**Code:**

```
$files= [];

  if($request->hasfile('resume'))
  {
    $files[] = $resumeFilename;
  }   
  if($request->hasfile('profile_photo'))
  {
    $files[] = $imagefilename;
  }
  if($request->hasfile('id_proof'))
  {
    $files[] = $id_proof;
  }
  if($request->hasfile('prevEmpType'))
  {
    $files[] = $prevEmpType;
  }
  if($request->hasfile('offer_letter'))
  {
    $files[] = $offer_letter;
  }
  if($request->hasfile('con_a_agree'))
  {
    $files[] = $con_a_agree;
  }

  foreach ($files as $file)
  {
    $file->move('uploads/' , $file); //Error is here i.e "Call to a member function move() on string"
  }
```

Uploading single file from each input type file field as in below screenshot.

**Error:**

[image: Screenshot of UI]

How to upload file in folder at once from multiple input filed?

Comment: add enctype="multipart/form-data" in html form

Comment: I added this, only one file is moved in folder and after throws error.

Comment: show full code  so we can see where is the error

Answer (score 0):

You can use Storage facade to save a file data

```php
$files= [];
if($request->hasfile('resume')) $files[] = $resumeFilename;
if($request->hasfile('profile_photo')) $files[] = $imagefilename;
if($request->hasfile('id_proof')) $files[] = $id_proof;
if($request->hasfile('prevEmpType')) $files[] = $prevEmpType;
if($request->hasfile('offer_letter')) $files[] = $offer_letter;
if($request->hasfile('con_a_agree')) $files[] = $con_a_agree;

// save the files
foreach ($files as $file) {
    $filename = sprintf('%s.%s', md5(\Str::random(5)), $file->getClientOriginalExtension());
    Storage::disk('uploads')->putFile($file, $filename);
}
```

You can get the file response with

```php
public function foo(string $filename)
{
    return response()->file(storage_path("app/uploads/$filename"));
}
```

Please read this [reference](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem) about using File Storage in Laravel

Comment: Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on string, I got this error.

Comment: other solution is to use a custom filename for your uploaded files

Comment: How to save filename in db using above code?